# Multivariate regression with variable size input

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, regression

I want to fit a machine/deep learning model to fit below table data format
F1-F5 are features and Y gets captured is a random time interval.

```
F1    F2    F3    F4    F5    Y
11    12    13    14    15    
.                             
.                             
.                             
n1    n2    n3    n4    n5    2.3
n+11  n+12  n+13  n+14  n+15
.
.
n+x1  n+x2  n+x3  n+x4  n+x5  3.5
```

I am confused to go whether to go with CNN kind of approach, multiplying 1*5 sized kernel through every row from 11-n1 and try to learn by matching sum with Y.
Kindly suggest me how to tackle such data.

**Note:**  F1 - F5 are sensors recording the data and each sensor has a definite purpose.

Comment: your predictor variables are definitely not independent, remove the multicollinearity first, then use random forest or if its linear just go with LR

Comment: @Oswald you mean, reduce feature space F1-F5 to single F1? If that is the case F1 - F5 are sensors recording the data and each sensor has a definite purpose. so i believe cannot have multicollinearity in this case.

Comment: Doesn't matter what purpose the sensors have, all columns are highly correlated (atleast, that it what it looks like in the data you have shown)

Comment: The data provided here is mock,  just to give an idea about the format. The predictor variables are independent, unfortunaltely i cannot share the data as it is sensitive. Is there any other approach?

Answer (score 1):

If ur features are not correlated, then u have to use all the five features. But still five is not big, so u don't need to go for a CNN. CNN is used in images, so as to reduce the number of parameters that will be needed for large number of features in an image. A 200*200 image has 40000 features and if we build a neural network we may need lakhs or even millions of parameter. That's why we go with CNN in such cases. But in ur case u only have 5 feature, so I think it is better to go with a simple neural network rather than CNN.